# Instantiate classes by link to the constructors with different amount of parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, instantiation

I am trying to create a method which can be used as a generic solution for instantiating different classes with different constructor parameters.

Here an example of this "imaginable" method, sort of my thoughts about how it should look:

```
module flashist
{
    export interface ISimpleClass<ObjectType>
    {
        new (): ObjectType;
    }

    export class Instantiator
    {
        public createInstance(Class: ISimpleClass<ClassType>, ...args): ClassType
        {
            // I understand, that this annotation is not possible
            var result: any = new Class.apply(args);
            return (result as ClassType);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem happens with the line:

```
var result: any = new Class.apply(args);
```

Where I want to pass unknown parameters to the constructor. I understand, that this syntax is not possible, I just wanted to show something similar to the thing I want to achieve.

So, my question is: do we have any solution for this problem in TypeScript and/or JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gound the way to implement what I needed by using the function **eval**:

```
var evalString: string = "new Class(";
args.forEach(
    (value: any, index: number, array: any[]): void =>
    {
        if (index > 0)
        {
            evalString += ",";
        }
        evalString += "args[" + index + "]";
    }
);
evalString += ");";

var result: any = eval(evalString);
```

I'm not sure if it's a normal practice to use the function **eval** (maybe there are some unknown for me drawbacks), but it works for me at the current stage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think there are two non-optimal solutions that may suit your use case.

1. Hardcode the parameters.

   ```
   public createInstance(Class: ISimpleClass<ClassType>, ...args): ClassType
   {
       var result:ClassType;
       if (args.length == 0)
           result = new ClassToCreate();
       if (args.length == 1)
           result = new ClassToCreate(args[0]);
       // ...
       if (args.length == 8)
           result = new ClassToCreate(args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3],args[4],args[5],args[6],args[7]);
       // ...

       return result;
   }
   ```

   I know, looks ugly.
2. Use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

   ```
   public createInstance(Class: ISimpleClass<ClassType>, ...args): ClassType
   {
       var result:any = Object.create(ClassToCreate.prototype); // create an object
       ClassToCreate.apply(result, args); // call the constructor

       return result;
   }
   ```

Like I said, none of them is optimal, but may help until you can find a better solution to your problem. Maybe pass just one `data` dictionary into every constructor?